# Login page lost backbone route in Safari iPad

Tags: ipad, backbone.js, authentication, safari, routes

I'm trying to redirect to a route from the login page but the navigator loses the route (#) in the process.

For example: I want to navigate to `/index.html#route`, but I have to login firstly, so the server show the login page, `/login.html` and forgets the #route hash

In chrome, IE11,... we have the route `.../login.html#route` (and we can do a manual redirect) but in Safari not, so I think it's a problem of the navigator, but I'm not sure.

My application uses spring-security and form authentication in the web.xml to manage the login page, and tiles to manage the URLs

Anyone have a similar problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally the app is served from a single html file (usually index.html). If you are going to a login page it would be index.html#login for example, unless you have enabled pushState and then it would be a normal looking url of just /login. If you go to login.html it is loading a different "app"..

Comment: The login page doesn't use backbone, we did it in that way to simplify and separate it from the rest of application, because this page is out of security of spring.

Comment: So when you redirect why don't you add `window.location.hash` to the link?

Comment: I do it with Chrome and IE11, but with Safari for windows or iPad it doesn't work, because window.location.hash has anything.